# Return column value in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and here's my issue.

I have a table `currentpercentage`.

This is the structure of the table `currentpercentage`

```
currentpercentage(**id**, name, total_cap, current_usage, created_at, updated_at)
```

I'm trying to calculate percentage of current usage; based on total_cap and current usage.

```
total_cap = 1000, 
current_usage = 237, 
name = User Name
```

In my controller i've setup a query to get the value of total_cap and the value of current_usage then calculate that the percentage would be.

When i call my query, it returns an array with the column name (total_cap) and value (1000). Same as when i query for current_usage.

```
{
"currentpercentage": [
{
"total_cap": 1000
}
    ]
}
```

I just want the query to return just the number (1000) without the array.

This is my query

```
$totalcap = CurrentPercentageModel::select('total_cap')->where('name', '=', 'User Name')->get();
```

How do I just get the `value`. Or is there an easier way to calculate the percentage from one query?

```
CurrentPercentageModel //What I use to connect to the database. DB Model
```

Comment: Try `$totalcap = CurrentPercentageModel::select('total_cap')->where('name', '=', 'User Name')->first();`

Comment: @FabioAntunes Response is null

Comment: The username is the correct one?

Comment: @FabioAntunes The username is correct. The response is correct as well but it's coming with the column name in the response ("total_cap": 1000) and all i want is the value 1000 so i can use it to calculate with other numbers.

Comment: Alright then you want `->value()` and not `->first()`, check my answer

Comment: @FabioAntunes It also returns null

Comment: it has to be `->value('And the Name of the column')` in your case `->value('total_cap')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113011/discussion-between-imbayago-and-fabio-antunes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `get` method which returns a collection even when you only have one row.

```
$totalcap = CurrentPercentageModel::select('total_cap')->where('name', '=', 'User Name')->get();
```

If you just want one record and one column value, then use the `value` method to get just the value of the column, more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results) (you might have to scroll a little bit)

```
$totalcap = CurrentPercentageModel::select('total_cap')->where('name', '=', 'User Name')->value('total_cap');
```